# creating a DTM from a 3 column CSV file with r

Tags: r, text-mining

I have that csv file, containing 600k lines and 3 rows, first one containing a disease name, second one a gene, a third one a number something like that: i have roughly 4k disease and 16k genes so sometimes the disease names and genes names are redudant.

cholera xx45 12
Cancer  xx65 1
cholera xx65 0

i would like to make a DTM matrix using R, i've been trying to use the Corpus command from the tm library but corpus doesn't reduce the amount of disease and size's 600k ish, i'd love to understand how to transform that file into a DTM.

I'm sorry for not being that precise, totally starting with computer science things as a bio guy :)
Cheers!

Comment: A bit unclear what you want here. You have a single file, so I'd initially expect you want a single row describing the frequency of each term of interest. Though I assume what you actually want is the the relationship between genes and diseases. That is, do you actually want a table that describes how many times each gene-disease combination occurs? (Side note, the structure of your csv is uncertain, "row" and "line" usually refer to the same thing. Do you mean 3 columns?)

Comment: the file that i have at the moment is for each line: one disease, one gene, one number what i would like to get now is a matrice with for each row, a disease, and for the columns every gene that is linked to that disease, i don't know if that makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned with the number in the third column, then you can accomplish what I think you're trying to do using only the first two columns (gene and disease).

Example with some simulated data:

```
library(data.table)

# Create a table with 10k combinations of ~6k different genes and 40 different diseases
df <- data.frame(gene=sapply(1:10000, function(x) paste(c(sample(LETTERS, size=2), sample(10, size=1)), collapse="")), disease=sample(40, size=100000, replace=TRUE))
```

table(df) creates a large matrix, nGenes rows  long and nDiseases columns wide. Looking at just the first 10 rows (because it's so large and sparse).

```
head(table(df))
      disease
gene   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
  AB10 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
  AB2  1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
  AB3  0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  3  0  1
  AB4  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 2 1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  2  0  0  0  1  1
  AB5  0 1 0 1 0 0 2 2 0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0
  AB6  0 0 2 0 2 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
      disease
gene   28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
  AB10  0  0  1  2  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  AB2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  AB3   0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0
  AB4   0  0  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  2  0  3  1
  AB5   0  2  1  1  0  0  3  4  0  1  1  0  2
  AB6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Alternatively, you can exclude the counts of 0 and only include combinations that actually exist. Easy aggregation can be done with data.table, e.g. (continuing from the above example)

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, .N, by=list(gene, disease)]
```

which gives a frequency table like the following:

```
       gene disease N
    1:  HA5      20 2
    2:  RF9      10 3
    3:  SD8      40 2
    4:  JA7      35 4
    5:  MJ2       1 2
   ---
75872: FR10      26 1
75873:  IC5      40 1
75874:  IU2      20 1
75875:  IG5      13 1
75876:  DW7      21 1
```